# Collecting online statistics for a non-online game

Tags: web-services

I want to collect statistics from an RPG game. This data should be stored in one place, online, so I can analyse it later.

Example of events -

1. Player achieved something
2. Player win the game using this way

So the question is : what is the best way, with minimum effort, to implement this functionality ?

I understand that I will have anyway to implement message sending functionality on the game's side.

I know that this can be implemented using Amazon SQS, but this doesn't seem to be the easiest way.

Idealy - it should be like that : I just send data from game, in form of messages. After that - I can retrieve the data from cloud storage and parse/analyze it.

P.S. I don't want a server at home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an existing service, you can build a simple webapp & receive events by REST urls.

Example:

```
http://my.statistics.server/achieve?player=123&category=456&level=789
http://my.statistics.server/win?player=123&score=12345
```

You could also packet the events up & append a keyed hash, if you want to make falsification a bit more difficult.

Example:

```
http://my.statistics.server/record?packet=<base64 data..., plus HMAC>
```

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Comment: Actually I would like to reuse an existing service.

Comment: Reuse is probably sensible, where you can.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platform you are going to write the game on, but I have used Flurry Analitica and it worked for my mobile games like 
[Flurry Analitics](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html)

Comment: Target platform is desktop. Thank you for suggestion, but it doesn't actually fit the needs.